# "Starting on [month]" versus "Starting in [month]"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the grammatically correct or better way of writting the following:

> 1. Starting *on* February, I noticed the change.
> 2. Starting *in* February, I noticed the change.

Comment: Hello Lucas! Welcome to EL&U please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). please consider whether your question might be better suited for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The general rule for time reference is:

- Use ***at*** for exact times: *at 10:45, at noon, at the equinox*
- Use ***on*** for dates: *on Saturday, on the tenth, on Labor Day*
- Use ***in*** for longer time periods: *in February, in a couple years, in the 20th century*

This parallels their use in spatial reference:

- *At* refers to a precise location, irrespective of dimension
  *at Eddie's place, at 55th and Halstead, at the office*
- *On* refers to location with respect to two-dimensional space
  *on the terrace, on the corner, on the lawn, on the table, on Halstead St*
- *In* refers to location with respect to three-dimensional space
  *in the living room, in the corner, in the yard, in the drawer, in the Empire State Building*

(If you're interested in the topic, there's more in [Fillmore's Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).)

Comment: So, the answer is *in* . . . (It's not clear what your "no" is referring to.)

Comment: Yes, starting ***in*** February.